# Enable Dropout with TFlite

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-lite

I trained a Dense Fully Connected Neural Network with Dropout in Keras and now would like to deploy it with TFlite. To sample actions from the model we keep dropout on during prediction-time (We use the model to optimize a Contextual Multi Armed Bandit.):

`prediction = model(X, training=True)`

**My question is:** Is there a way to keep dropout on also in a tflite model? Maybe hardcode dropout as on?

So that we can also sample actions from a deployed model.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to keep dropout on.
Two things have to be done.

1. Set training flag in Dropout layer when building keras model (this enables Dropout all the time)

```
x = Dropout(0.1)(x, training=True)
```

2. Set TFlite converter Flags

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(actor.model)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
                tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,  # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
                tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS  # enable TensorFlow ops.
            ]
tflite_model = converter.convert()

open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Sadly this increases model load time a bit.

Reference:
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select